# Scrolling div issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to solve a problem with scrolling on website. Take a look at this 
[site](http://www.firstscribe.com/).
Scrolling down causes to slide up the "hidden" part of site. I wanna achieve the same effect, and it needs to be smooth sliding as well. I've tried to use scrollTop() and animate() but it doesn't work. I'm using JQuery. Let me post my code, here it is:

**HTML**

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
    <link href="stylin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function(){
            $(".button").toggle(function(){
                $("#blocks").animate({top: 200}, 500 );
            },
            function(){ 
                $("#blocks").animate({top: 760}, 500 );
            });
        });
    </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready( function() {
     $(document).scroll( function() {
     $("#blocks").animate({top: (780-$(this).scrollTop())}, 1000 );

    });
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="photo">
        </div>
        <div id="blocks">
            <div id="button_block">
                <a href="#" class="button" ><img src="scrollup.png" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
    #main {
    width: 1500px; 
    position:absolute;

}

#photo{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:1500px;
    height:780px;
    background-color:blue;
    z-index:0;

}

#blocks{
    position:absolute;
    top: 760px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index:1;
}

#button_block{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:64px;
    top:-32px;
}

.button
{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 686px;
}
```

Div **blocks** should be the one sliding up while scrolling.

Look at this part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready( function() {
         $(document).scroll( function() {
         $("#blocks").animate({top: (780-$(this).scrollTop())}, 1000 );

        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: You're using a very old version of jQuery there.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#main {
    width: 1500px; 
    position:absolute;

}

#photo{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:1500px;
    height:780px;
    background-color:blue;
    z-index:0;

}

#blocks{
    position:absolute;
    top: 760px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index:1;
}

#button_block{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:64px;
    top:-32px;
}

.button
{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 686px;
}

#scroll_to_top{
   display:none;
   position:fixed;
   bottom:15px;
   right:20px;
   opacity:0.8;
   z-index:9999;
}
#scroll_to_top:hover{
   opacity:1;
}
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
    <link href="stylin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function(){
            $(".button").toggle(function(){
                $("#blocks").animate({top: 200}, 500 );
            },
            function(){ 
                $("#blocks").animate({top: 760}, 500 );
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var stt_is_shown = false;
            $(window).scroll(function(){
            var win_height = 300;
            var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop(); 
            if (scroll_top > win_height && !stt_is_shown) {
                stt_is_shown = true;
                $("#scroll_to_top").fadeIn();
            } else if (scroll_top < win_height && stt_is_shown) {
                        stt_is_shown = false;
                        $("#scroll_to_top").fadeOut();
                        }else if{
                           <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready( function() {
     $(document).scroll( function() {
     $("#blocks").animate({top: (780-$(this).scrollTop())}, 1000 );
}
    });
});
</script>
            });
            $("#scroll_to_top").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1000);
            });
        });
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready( function() {
     $(document).scroll( function() {
     $("#blocks").animate({top: (780-$(this).scrollTop())}, 1000 );

    });
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="photo">
        </div>
        <div id="blocks">
            <div id="button_block">
                <a href="#" class="button" ><img src="scrollup.png" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="scroll_to_top"><img src="scrollup.png" /></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I changed the if else statements and added a new one try it!

Comment: That's not what i meant. Skip the buttons, scroll_to_top button scrolls the page up, it works fine, the other button also works and i wanna make the same effect using the scroll bar. Have you looked at this page?[link](http://www.firstscribe.com/) Scrolling your mouse causes the rest of the page to slide up or down, depends on your scrolling direction.

Comment: What do you mean what effect do you want the scroll bar to do then?

Comment: Do you want  the top bar to do the same thing or something? please be more descriptive.

Comment: [link](http://zapodaj.net/91731ab1b22bd.jpg.html) look at this please. It moves so smooth.

Comment: IK it does i did look at several times.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready( function() {
     $(document).scroll( function() {
   $("#blocks").animate({top: (780-$(this).scrollTop())}, 1000 );
  
    });
});
</script>` This is a script i have problem with. I wanna achieve the effect, the photo div it's fixed, stays at top all the time, while scrolling your mouse, blocks div should cover photo div. Smooth as i show you at previous site.

Comment: ok so thats the java that goes into the header file, and makes the function (scroll function) and declares what it does ok?

Comment: Ok hey im getting a warning I can help you ive taken two college courses for this want to move this to a chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75907/discussion-between-noah-mayo-and-kobasek).

Comment: Ok I got it! You need to put this in the if statement in the script and get follow it up with the else and put the code that was there in another else<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready( function() { $(document).scroll( function() { $("#blocks").animate({top: (780-$(this).scrollTop())}, 1000 ); }); }); </script>

Comment: yeah I can although I cannot run the website just to lets you know.

Comment: Hey do you have to have this done by a certain time?

Comment: Nope, but it's still not what i'm trying to achieve ;D Leave the buttons, they work fine, it's all about scrolling with your mouse or scroll bar.

Comment: Do you work for that company and thats how they want it or something?

Comment: I just need to do it that way. I've searched for related topics on internet but i haven't found any similar.

Comment: Ok then Have you gone to W3schools.com that has a lot of helpful stuff

Comment: Im going to bed see you its 2 in te moring for me i have to get up at 6 so..... talk to you later I guess